# How to return records grouped by column A having different values in column B

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, group-by, common-table-expression

Pardon the title but this is what I have in table `#RISK`

```
ACCT_NUM  RISK
1234       5
007       10
007        1
37947      3
```

I want the output as -

```
ACCT_NUM  RISK
007        10
007        1
```

This is what I have tried -

```
;WITH C AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ACCT_NUM ORDER BY ACCT_NUM, RISK) AS Rn
           ,ACCT_NUM, RISK
    FROM #RISK 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT ACCT_NUM,RISK FROM #RISK GROUP BY ACCT_NUM,RISK)

)
SELECT *
FROM C
```

But my query is not returning any results. What is it that I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can achieve this result by using count and Row_number function also

```
declare @t table (AcctNum varchar(10),risk int)
insert into @t(AcctNum,risk)values
('1234',5),
('007',10),
('007',1),
('37947',3)


;with cte as (
select AcctNum,risk,COUNT(AcctNum)OVER(PARTITION BY AcctNum )RN from @t )
select AcctNum,risk from cte WHERE RN = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select acct_num, risk
from (select r.*,
             min(risk) over (partition by acct_num) over minrisk,
             max(risk) over (partition by acct_num) over maxrisk
      from #risk r
     ) r
where minrisk <> maxrisk;
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this helps

```
SELECT ACCT_NUM,RISK FROM #RISK
where ACCT_NUM=(
SELECT ACCT_NUM FROM #RISK
GROUP BY ACCT_NUM 
HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```